# Reverse ssh tunnel in with .ssh/config

Tags: ssh, configuration, ssh-tunneling

How can I establish a reverse ssh tunnel with my ./ssh/config file?

I'm trying to reproduce this command

```
ssh admin@dmx.com -L 4444:restricedserver1.org:4420 -L 4445:restricedserver2:4430
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The option is called `RemoteForward` with a bit different syntax.

But in your example, you are using `LocalForward`, which would look like this in `ssh_config`:

```
Host dmx.com
  User admin
  LocalForward 4444 restricedserver1.org:4420
  LocalForward 4445 restricedserver2:4430
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a tunnel.  Use `ProxyCommand` instead:

```
Host restricedserver1
    HostName        restricedserver1.org
    User            admin
    Port            4420
    ProxyCommand    ssh -A -q -l %r -W %h:4444 dmx.com
    ControlMaster   auto
    ControlPersist  5m
```

and similar for the other host.  The advantage over a tunnel is that you don't need to keep it up all the time.