# Create ssh config to VNC server with tunnel via intermediate machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, ssh-config, vncviewer

I recently found out about ssh config file where one can setup frequently used ssh connections. However, I am having troubles transforming one command which connects my computer to VNCServer running on my server which is hidden behind intermediate server. Basically transform this command (which works):

```bash
ssh -t -L port1:localhost:port2 user1@machine1.com ssh -L port2:localhost:port3 user2@machine.com
```

with `vncviewer localhost:0` in separate window, into ssh config file. I managed to create a config which connect to the machine without throwing any `Failed to set up port` messages, but when I run in separate terminal window

```bash
vncviewer localhost:0
```

I get an error. In case the ~/.ssh/config is set in this way (my own try):

```
 Host machine1
   HostName machine1.com
   User user1
   LocalForward port1 localhost:port2
   RequestTTY force

 Host machine2
   HostName machine2.com
   User user2
   LocalForward port2 localhost:port3
   ProxyJump machine1
```

and ran by running `ssh machine2` and then `vncviewer localhost:0` in new terminal window the error is `"Failed to connect to localhost:0": unable to connect to socket: Connection refused (111).`

In the case I set it up as mention [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303993/reverse-ssh-tunnel-in-with-ssh-config):

```
Host machine2
  HostName machine2.com
  User user2
  LocalForward port1 user1@machine1:port2
  LocalForward port2 user2@machine2:port3
  RequestTTY force
```

I get an error saying `The connection was dropped by the server before the session could be established.`
In both cases I connect to machine2 in terminal window and can browse stuff. But I would like to connect to the vncserver also.

Can you please explain what am I doing wrong here? I was consulting these sources when creating any other ssh config:
https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/ --- beginners guide

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html --- to look definition of every -t -L I used

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-config --- to translate -t -L to ssh config command

https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example --- to explain wheter I need LocalForward or Remote Forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first configuration seems fine. As for the second configuration `LocalForward` requires a `hostname` and you've provided `user@address` see [1].

Go with your first configuration (I've edited your first config below) and run

```
ssh -v -J machine1 machine2 -NL <p1>:localhost:<p2> # -v print ssh debugging messages
# <p1> : port on your computer
# <p2> : vnc port on machine2
```

Edited ssh config:

```
 Host machine1
   HostName machine1.com
   User user1
   #Port 22

 Host machine2
   HostName machine2.com
   User user2
   ProxyJump machine1
   #Port 22
   #LocalForward <p1> localhost:<p2>
   # <p1> port on your computer
   # <p2> port on machine2
```

[0] ssh with `-v` flag will allow you to understand what's going wrong with your connection.

[1] https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

[2] More info on proxy jump https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two

[3] More info on proxy jump https://www.infoworld.com/article/3619278/proxyjump-is-safer-than-ssh-agent-forwarding.go

Comment: Thank you, your comment worked for me. However, this command does not seem to simplify the connection. I will try to browse through the suggestions you provided and try to simplify it even more.

Comment: By simplify do you mean smaller command?  Since ProxyJump machine1 is mentioned in config therefore you can remove the -J machine1 and the command becomes ssh -v machine2 -NL <p1>:localhost:<p2>. You can further remove -v and -L <p1>:localhost:<p2> and un-comment LocalForward <p1> localhost:<p2> in the config.

Comment: I uncommented the `LocalForward <p1> localhost:<p2>` in machine 2 and removed `-J  machine1` and now it works just by putting `ssh machine2`. Thank you a lot!

EDIT: you were faster by 9 seconds. thanks